# Copy files from AWS S3 bucket to SFTP using Paramiko

Tags: python, amazon-s3, sftp, boto3, paramiko

I have a requirement where I need to copy all CSV files from the S3 bucket to SFTP location.

I am able to connect and connection established but I was not sure how to move files using Paramiko.

Following code:

```
print('Establishing SFTP connection with ' + hostname + ' at port: ' + port)
filebjects = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name)
# print(filebjects)

try:
    print("port")
    # return

    bucket = s3_rs.Bucket(str(keybucket))
    for obj in bucket.objects.all():
        key = obj.key
        body = obj.get()['Body'].read()
        decodedKey = body.decode('utf-8')

    key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(StringIO(decodedKey))
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    transport = paramiko.Transport((hostname,int(port)))
    transport.connect(username=username,pkey=key)
    sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)

    print("sftp")
    client.put(localpath="fileName",remotepath="SFTP_REMO_FOLDER",)

    sftp.chdir(path=remote_directory)

    print(sftp.listdir(path='.'))

    # for object in filebjects['Contents']:
    #     obj=client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name,Key=fileName)
    #     file_data = obj['Body'].read()
    #     print(file_data)


    # return
    transport.close()
```

I am not sure what should be in the file name here I am getting all objects and file name separate. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
sftp.putfo(BytesIO(body), "/remote/path/name.ext")
```

---

Though there's a more efficient way by retrieving file-like object directly from S3, rather than copying the contents over twice. See [Transfer file from AWS S3 to SFTP using Boto 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58719309/850848).