# Transfer file from SFTP to S3 using Paramiko

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, sftp, paramiko

I am using Paramiko to access a remote SFTP folder, and I'm trying to write code that transfers files from a path in SFTP (with a simple logic using the file metadata to check it's last modified date) to AWS S3 bucket.
I have set the connection to S3 using Boto3, but I still can't seem to write a working code that transfers the files without downloading them to a local directory first. Here is some code I tried using Paramiko's `getfo()` method. But it doesn't work.

```
for f in files:
    # get last modified from file metadata
    last_modified = sftp.stat(remote_path + f).st_mtime
    last_modified_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(last_modified).date()
    if last_modified_date > date_limit:  # check limit
       print('getting ' + f)
       full_path = f"{folder_path}{f}"
       fo = sftp.getfo(remote_path + f,f)
       s3_conn.put_object(Body=fo,Bucket=s3_bucket, Key=full_path)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [Paramiko `SFTPClient.open`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.open) to get a file-like object that you can pass to [Boto3 `Client.put_object`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/put_object.html):

```
with sftp.open(remote_path + f, "r") as f:
    f.prefetch()
    s3_conn.put_object(Body=f)
```

*For the purpose of the `f.prefetch()`, see [Reading file opened with Python Paramiko SFTPClient.open method is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58433996/850848)*.

---

For the opposite direction, see:
[Transfer file from AWS S3 to SFTP using Boto 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58719309/850848)

Comment: still really slow, change it to Body=f.read() that fixes it

Comment: @user433342 But that loads whole file to memory.

Comment: Yes, yes it does, but it takes 1 second per file instead of 1 minute per megabyte

Comment: @user433342 So if you have an alternative solution, post it as an answer.

Comment: Ur solution was fine just needed a tweak, thanks for it!