# Recursively move files from SFTP to S3 preserving structure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bigdata, boto3, pysftp

I'm trying to recursively move files from an SFTP server to S3, possibly using `boto3`. I want to preserve the folder/file structure as well. I was looking to do it this way:

```
import pysftp

private_key = "/mnt/results/sftpkey"

srv = pysftp.Connection(host="server.com", username="user1", private_key=private_key)

srv.get_r("/mnt/folder", "./output_folder")
```

Then take those files and upload them to S3 using `boto3`. However, the folders and files on the server are numerous with deep levels and also large in size. So my machine ends up running out of memory and disk space. I was thinking of a script where I could download single files and upload single files and then delete and repeat.

I know this would take a long time to finish, but I can run this as a job without running out of space and not keep my machine open the entire time. Has anyone done something similar? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't (or don't want) to download all of the files at once before sending them to S3, then you need to download them one at a time.

Further, from there, it follows that you'll need to build a list of files to download, then work on them, transferring one file to your local computer, then sending it to S3.

A very simple version of this would look something like this:

```python
import pysftp
import stat
import boto3
import os
import json

# S3 bucket and prefix to upload to
target_bucket = "example-bucket"
target_prefix = ""
# Root FTP folder to sync
base_path = "./"
# Both base_path and target_prefix should end in a "/"
# Or, for the prefix, be empty for the root of the bucket
srv = pysftp.Connection(
    host="server.com", 
    username="user1", 
    private_key="/mnt/results/sftpkey",
)

if os.path.isfile("all_files.json"):
    # No need to cache files more than once. This lets us restart 
    # on a failure, though really we should be caching files in 
    # something more robust than just a json file
    with open("all_files.json") as f:
        all_files = json.load(f)
else:
    # No local cache, go ahead and get the files
    print("Need to get list of files...")
    todo = [(base_path, target_prefix)]
    all_files = []

    while len(todo):
        cur_dir, cur_prefix = todo.pop(0)
        print("Listing " + cur_dir)
        for cur in srv.listdir_attr(cur_dir):
            if stat.S_ISDIR(cur.st_mode):
                # A directory, so walk into it
                todo.append((cur_dir + cur.filename + "/", cur_prefix + cur.filename + "/"))
            else:
                # A file, just add it to our cache
                all_files.append([cur_dir + cur.filename, cur_prefix + cur.filename])

    # Save the cache out to disk    
    with open("all_files.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(all_files, f)

# And now, for every file in the cache, download it
# and turn around and upload it to S3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
while len(all_files):
    ftp_file, s3_name = all_files.pop(0)

    print("Downloading " + ftp_file)
    srv.get(ftp_file, "_temp_")
    print("Uploading " + s3_name)
    s3.upload_file("_temp_", target_bucket, s3_name)

    # Clean up, and update the cache with one less file
    os.unlink("_temp_")
    with open("all_files.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(all_files, f)

srv.close()
```

Error checking, and speed improvements are obviously possible.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. Will add error handling and logging to this

Answer (score 2):

You have to do it file-by-file.

Start with the recursive download code here:
[Python pysftp get_r from Linux works fine on Linux but not on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50118919/850848)

After each `sftp.get`, do S3 upload and remove the file.

Actually you can even copy the file from SFTP to S3 without storing the file locally:
[Transfer file from SFTP to S3 using Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65787027/850848)