# Using Python pysftp download files from SFTP and store directly in AWS S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, sftp, pysftp

Using Python trying to download files from SFTP using pysftp module and save the files directly in S3 bucket. I should not save the files in my local. They should be directly saved into S3. I could not find an option to put the files directly in s3.

I am using using private SSH keys instead of password to connect SFTP. Secrets are stored in AWS secret manager. Please help.

```
import boto3
import json

def get_secret():
  client = boto3.client("secretsmanager")
  secret_name = "arn:name"
  region_name = "region"
  response = client.get_secret_value(SecretId=secret_name)
  secret_dict = json.loads(response['SecretString'])
  return secret_dict 

sftp_secret = get_secret()
host=sftp_secret["host"]
username=sftp_secret["username"]
private_key=sftp_secret["private_key"]

with pysftp.Connection(host=host, username=username, private_key=private_key) as sftp:
    print("connection established")
    sftp.cwd('/')
    list_dir = sftp.listdir_attr()
    sftp.get(remote_path, local_path)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, do not use pysftp, it's a dead project. See [pysftp vs. Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48434941/850848).

Use Paramiko instead:
[Transfer file from SFTP to S3 using Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65787027/850848)

And even if you decide to stick with the pysftp, the solution is basically the same. The [pysftp `Connection.open`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.open) works the same way as [Paramiko `SFTPClient.open`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.open).