# S3ToSFTP: Move multiple files from same S3 key to SFTP path

Tags: python, amazon-s3, sftp

**Requirement**: Move multiple files from the same S3 Key to SFTP

Below is the part of the code, I was able to achieve moving one file into SFTP location.
If the s3_key location has more than 1 file example as below, I need to get both files from /path/output to SFTP Location

```
/path/output/abc.csv
/path/output/def.csv
```

**Tried:** But both files are not posted

```
Tried passing s3_key as '/path/output/*.csv'
```

**Code**

```
with sftp.open(sftp_path + key_name, 'wb') as f:
     s3_client.download_fileobj(s3_bucket,s3_key, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Boto3 to download all files from a S3 Bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31918960/850848).

Except that instead of downloading the files to a local file:

```
client.download_file(bucket, k, dest_pathname)
```

... you will stream them to SFTP:

```
with sftp.open(sftp_path + file.get('Key'), 'wb', 32768) as f:
    client.download_file(bucket, k, f)
```

*Note that this simple change does not handle "subfolders".*

*For the purpose of the `32768` argument, see [Writing to a file on SFTP server opened using pysftp "open" method is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58111798/850848)*.