# Upload excel file to sftp server

Tags: python, paramiko

I have the below code, which uploads a df in csv format into a sftp server.

```
with sftp.open(mypath + timestr + '.csv', "w") as f:
    f.write(df_pdcs_ec.to_csv(index=False))
```

However: is there a way to upload that same df but in excel format?

Update: I'm trying to generate the file with 2 tabs as per @furas's answer, but only getting one.

```
with sftp.open(mypath + timestr + '.xlsx', "wb") as f:
    df_pdcs_ec.to_excel(f, sheet_name = 'Test1', index=False)
    df_pdcs_ec.to_excel(f, sheet_name = 'Test2', index=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test it but in `Pandas` all functions should work with `file handlers` or `file-like objects` which have function `write()` so you can open file or connection and use `to_csv(file_handler)` `to_excel(file_handler)`, etc.

But for `excel` you have to write it in bytes mode - `wb`

```
with sftp.open(mypath + timestr + '.csv', "wb") as f:
    df_pdcs_ec.to_csv(f, index=False)

with sftp.open(mypath + timestr + '.xlsx', "wb") as f:
    df_pdcs_ec.to_excel(f, index=False)

with sftp.open(mypath + timestr + '.html', "wb") as f:
    df_pdcs_ec.to_html(f, index=False)
```

---

**EDIT:**

To save many tabs you have to use `ExcelWriter` (see doc: [to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html))

I can't test it with `sftp.open()` but this should work. At least it works with standard `open()`.

```
with sftp.open(mypath + timestr + '.xlsx', "wb") as f:
    with pd.ExcelWriter(f) as writer:
        df_pdcs_ec.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Test1', index=False)
        df_pdcs_ec.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Test2', index=False)
```

Comment: +1 Though you will want to set also `bufsize` parameter. See [Writing to a file on SFTP server opened using pysftp “open” method is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58111798/850848) (it's about pysftp, but that's just a wrapper around Paramiko, which has the same problem).

Comment: If I try that, my format breaks to PK?a]I:O[Content_Types].xml­”ËnÂ0E÷ýŠÈÛ*1tQUEË©ô\{B,Ûòþ¾“ðP[Q ‚M¬dîÜsÇŽ<-—- ¡
¾ý¢'2ð:ë§¥xŸ<çw"CRÞ(<”b(FÃ«Ád3nöXŠš(ÞK‰º†Fa"x®T!5Šø5MeTz¦¦ oz½[©ƒ'ð”Së!†ƒG¨ÔÜQö´äÏë 
How can I fix this?

Comment: how did you open it ? Excel is not text file but compressed file and you can't open it in editor or display like `.csv`. Maybe it needs extension `.xlsx` because as I remeber `.xlsx` is `xml` compressed by `zip` and in your text I see `.xml` and `PK` which can means `zip` compression.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl thanks for the input! What's the default for that bufsize parameter?

Comment: @furas that was it, I needed to save it in .xlsx. Last issue I'm facing: please see my update.

Comment: I'm not sure but second tab may need to open in `append mode`

Comment: documentation for [to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) shows `If you wish to write to more than one sheet in the workbook, it is necessary to specify an ExcelWriter object:`.

Comment: @furas so,  there is no option to upload a multiple tab excel to a sftp server?

Comment: I can't test it but maybe you will need `with sftp.open(...) as f: with pd.ExcelWriter(f) as writer: df.to_excel(writer, ...)`. OR you should write in `io.BytesIO` and send this `io.BytesIO`

Comment: That was exactly was I was hoping for. Thanks a lot!