# Save PIL image to a SFTP folder (PNG or PDF) using Paramiko

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, sftp, paramiko

I need your help to save a PIL "image" to a server (SFTP) using the following example:

```
transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
transport.connect(username=user, password=pwd)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)

w, h = 220, 190
image = Image.new("RGB", (w, h))

file = sftp.file("/volume/file.png", "w", -1) # the volume folder is located in the server
file.write(image)
file.flush()
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should use [`Image.save`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save):

```
with sftp.open("/volume/file.png", "w", 32768) as fp:
    image.save(fp)
```

---

*For the purpose of the `32768` parameter, see [Writing to a file on SFTP server opened using Paramiko/pysftp "open" method is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58111798/850848)*.