# Why is Paramiko SFTP-upload so much slower, than command-line sftp?

Tags: sftp, paramiko

I'm trying to upload *large* files to a remote SFTP-server. The regular OpenSSH `sftp`-client averages 4-5 Mb/second.

My code is:

```py
    inp = open(fName, "rb")
    bsize = os.stat(inp.fileno()).st_blksize
    out = SFTP.open(os.path.split(fName)[-1], "w",
        bsize * 4) # SFTP is a result of paramiko.SFTPClient()
    out.set_pipelined()

    while True:
        buf = inp.read(bsize)
        if not buf:
            break
        out.write(buf)

    inp.close()
    out.close()
```

Averages 40-180Kb -- even if I artificially raise the `bsize`. One could blame the fact, that Paramiko is a "pure Python" implementation, but the difference should not be *this* huge...

There is no significant CPU-load on my machine, which runs FreeBSD-11, python-3.6, Paramiko-2.7.1

What's going on?

*Update*: adding `out.set_pipelined()` helps raise the throughput to 1-2Mb/s, but it still lags behinds that of the OpenSSH `sftp`-client by a lot...

*Update*: adding an explicit buffer-size to the `SFTP.open()` call -- as suggested by Martin in a comment -- had no perceptible effect. (I suspect, Paramiko already uses some buffering by default.)

Comment: See [Writing to a file on SFTP server opened using Paramiko/pysftp "open" method is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58111798/850848).

Comment: Thanks, I read that -- no help from adding the buffer-size :-(

Comment: If you know that, edit your question and code to acknowledge that information.

Comment: What is the value of `bsize * 4`?

Comment: `655360 * 4` -- or 2621440 is the largest I tried.