# Download chunk of the large file using pysftp in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sftp, paramiko, pysftp

I have one use case in which I want to read only top 5 rows of a large CSV file which is present in one of my sftp server and I don't want to download the complete file to just read the top 5 rows. I am using `pysftp` in Python to interact with my SFTP server. Do we have any way in which I can download only the chunk of the file instead of downloading the complete file in `pysftp`?

If there are any other libraries in Python or any technique I can use, please guide me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*First, do not use pysftp. It's dead unmaintained project. Use Paramiko instead.  See [pysftp vs. Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48434941/850848)*.

If you want to read data from specific point in the file, you can open a file-like object representing the remote file using Paramiko [`SFTPClient.open`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.open) method (or equivalent pysftp [`Connection.open`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.open)) and then use it as if you were accessing data from any local file:

- Use `.seek` to set read pointer to the desired offset.
- Use `.read` to read data.

```
with sftp.open("/remote/path/file", "r", bufsize=32768) as f:
    f.seek(offset)
    data = f.read(count)
```

For the purpose of `bufsize`, see:
[Writing to a file on SFTP server opened using Paramiko/pysftp "open" method is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58111798/850848)